# Woocommerce custom search

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, search, customization

I want to build a search form on the homepage where people can search by

- Product Name
- Product Category
- Price range

I have found a few results, but a lot of them are filters which display products.

Instead I want people to fill out the form, and bring any product up that:

- Matches the string written in the product name field (eg if you type in "sh", products that have "shirt" in the name will appear.
- Matches the product category
- Is within the defined price range

Is there a solution out there already like this, or code I can view to use?
I do have PHP knowledge, just generally new to the wordpress/woocommerce way of doing things.

Thanks